# Need help in character recognition

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing, ocr, correlation

I am not getting the use of if-else statements where it is written if ind==1 || ind==2 what is it comparing and how can it say that if it is equal to 1 or 2 then letter A, if 3 or 4 the letter B  etc. Can anyone help me regarding this? The if-else statements how can we randomly give any number or the numbers compared have some meaning?

% This is a function called from the main file.

````
function letter=readLetter(snap)

load NewTemplates 
  snap=imresize(snap,[42 24]); 
  rec=[ ];

  for n=1:length(NewTemplates)
      cor=corr2(NewTemplates{1,n},snap); 
      rec=[rec cor]; 
  end

  ind=find(rec==max(rec));
  display(ind);

% Alphabets listings.
  if ind==1 || ind==2
     letter='A';

  elseif ind==3 || ind==4

     letter='B';

  elseif ind==5

     letter='C';

  elseif ind==6 || ind==7

     letter='D';

  elseif ind==8

     letter='E';

  elseif ind==9

     letter='F';

                  ``` like so up to Z and 0 -9 ```
  end
  end
````

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab OR operator can be written as `||`. For example in your case:

```
if ind==1 || ind==2
    letter='A';
```

Means: if `ind` is equal to `1` OR `ind` is equal to `2` - do the instruction (Set `letter` variable to `'A'`).

However in this case `switch` would have more sense. For example:

````
switch ind
    case {1,2}
        letter='A';
    case {3,4}
        letter='B';
    case 5
        letter='C';

 ``` like so up to Z and 0 -9 ```

    otherwise
        disp('Nothing matches')
````

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer upon some debugging. The values that are being compared to are coming from the .mat file that is created by MATLAB to store the binaries of the images. 1 2 3 ... are the columns of respective Letters stored in .mat file. I converted the binary to image and it was correct.